# Create a jar file of Java source file

Tags: java, jar

How to create a jar file of Java source file?

I have one class called `CreateJar` which has function Calculate which
calculate the addition of two integers. I called this function in
another class called `UseFunction`, but I want to create a jar file of
`CreateJar` class and want to import this in `UseFunction` class.  I Googled
for it but not get any solution.

Below are my classes:

### CreateJar

```
package com.dir;

public class CreateJar {

    public int Calculate(int x,int y)
    {
        int z =x+y;
        return z;
    }
}
```

### UseFunction

```
package com.dir;

public class UseFunction {
    CreateJar jar = new CreateJar();

    public UseFunction()
    {
        System.out.println(jar.Calculate(5, 6));
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new UseFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I Googled
for it but not get any solution."* What search terms did you use?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, refer below link http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm Thanks

Comment: Did you consider visiting the Java Tutorials? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html

Answer (score 4):

1.Create a file named CreateJar.java

```
package com.dir;

public class CreateJar {
    public int Calculate(int x,int y)
    {
        int z =x+y;         
        return z;
    }    
}
```

2.Create a file named UseFunction.java:

```
package com.dir;

//import com.dir.CreateJar;

public class UseFunction {
    CreateJar jar = new CreateJar();
    public UseFunction()
    {
        System.out.println(jar.Calculate(5, 6));
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new UseFunction();
    }

}
```

3.Compile the first file:

```
javac CreateJar.java
```

The compliled result will be "CreateJar.class"

4.Create directory structure for the package "com.dir".To do that,simply create a directory "com" and another directory "dir" in "com".

5.Copy or move "CreateJar.class" to com/dir

6.Pack it with Jar:

```
jar -cf myLib.jar com\dir\CreateJar.class
```

7.Compile "UseFunction.java" by referencing dir.jar:

```
javac -cp myLib.jar UseFunction.java
or
javac -classpath myLib.jar UseFunction.java
```

8.Note:If your UseFunction.java is not in the same package(com.dir) as the referenced class(CreateJar).Then you may need to add this line in UseFunction.java.

```
import com.dir.CreateJar;
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic format of the command for creating a JAR file is:

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

The options and arguments used in this command are:

> - The `c` option indicates that you want to create a JAR file.
> - The `f` option indicates that you want the output to go to a file rather than to stdout.
> - `jar-file` is the name that you want the resulting JAR file to have. You can use any filename for a JAR file.  By convention, JAR filenames are given a `.jar` extension, though this is not required.
> - The `input-file`(s) argument is a space-separated list of one or more files that you want to include in your JAR file. The `input-file`(s) argument can contain the wildcard `*` symbol. If any of the "input-files" are directories, the contents of those directories are added to the JAR archive recursively.
>
> The `c` and `f` options can appear in either order, but there must not be any space between them.

For more details visit [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

Try this link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html